# join two dataframes so that a column contains multiple values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, spread

My data looks like this:

```
df1
#>           Artist          Album Year
#> 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967
#> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971
```

and

```
df2
#>    Artist Members
#> 1 Beatles  George
#> 2 Beatles   Ringo
#> 3 Beatles    Paul
#> 4 Beatles    John
```

And I would like to join these two dfs, in what I believe is an "untidy" fashion. Despite the untidyness, it will be very helpful for me to have the final output look like the example below, where every band (Artist) only takes up one row, and the band members are all put into one column, separated by say commas:

```
Desired Output
#>           Artist          Album                   Members Year
#> 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's George, Ringo, Paul, John 1967
#> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers                           1971
```

I've been able to get close to a solution (below), but:

1. Is there a simpler way to do this?
2. How can I generalise my code so that if there is a band with say 11 members, or 13 members, the code will still work?
3. When data is missing, like for the Rolling Stones, the values are "NA". Is it easy to make them blank?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      Artist = c("Beatles", "Rolling Stones"),
       Album = c("Sgt. Pepper's", "Sticky Fingers"),
        Year = c(1967, 1971)
)

df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
       Artist = c("Beatles", "Beatles", "Beatles", "Beatles"),
    Members = c("George", "Ringo", "Paul", "John")
)

df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Artist")
df <- df %>% group_by(Artist) %>% mutate(member_number = seq_along(Members))
df <- spread(df, key = "member_number", value = "Members", sep = "_")
df <- df %>% unite(col = "members", member_number_1:member_number_4, sep = ",")
```

Which gives the output

```
df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   Artist [2]
#>   Artist         Album           Year members               
#>   <chr>          <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                 
#> 1 Beatles        Sgt. Pepper's   1967 George,Ringo,Paul,John
#> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers  1971 NA,NA,NA,NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

slightly differently:

```
library(dplyr)


 left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
    group_by(Artist, Album, Year) %>% 
    summarise(members = paste(Members, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Artist, Album [?]
  Artist         Album           Year members               
  <chr>          <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                 
1 Beatles        Sgt. Pepper's   1967 George,Ringo,Paul,John
2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers  1971 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `left_join` and then `summarise` multiple columns and collapse them into `unique` comma-separated strings.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "Artist") %>%
   group_by(Artist) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(Album:Members), ~toString(unique(.)))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Artist         Album          Year  Members                  
#  <chr>          <chr>          <chr> <chr>                    
#1 Beatles        Sgt. Pepper's  1967  George, Ringo, Paul, John
#2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, on = .(Artist)][, .(members = toString(Members)),
   .(Artist, Album, Year)]
#          Artist          Album Year                   members
#1:        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967 George, Ringo, Paul, John
#2: Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971                        NA
```

Comment: Can reduce to one step: `setDT(df1)[df2, on = .(Artist), members := toString(i.Members)]`

Comment: @sindri_baldur  Thank you Sindri.  You are a great guy!

Answer (score 0):

My package *safejoin* allows aggregation operations on the joined table by the joining variable :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% eat(df2, .agg = toString)
# Joining, by = "Artist"
#           Artist          Album Year                   Members
# 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967 George, Ringo, Paul, John
# 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971                      <NA>
```